# Display data from two tables if one table empty display from other php

Tags: php

I have a simple query that is retrieving data from two tables let say employee and employee_images, so what i am doing is that i am registering the employee from one form and in this form image is not necessary but later on can be added. Now i am displaying data on a page where is wrote query something like this

```
Select * from employee JOIN employee_images ON employee.id=employee_images.emp_id;
```

So if both tables contains data then the record will be shown but if employee only register and does not upload images his record is not displaying at the page so what query should i make to display data from both tables even if images of any user is not uploaded. Assume that employee table has an id of 1 but employee_images table does not have any data yet. but i have to display data from both tables by combining them. Solution needs using JOIN condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get employees both with and without images, try using a `left join`:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   employee 
LEFT JOIN employee_images ON employee.id=employee_images.emp_id;
```

This will return NULL for the columns in `employee_images` for those rows that do not have images, and a populated value for those that do.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Outer Join In the above query should be:
Select * from employee LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_images ON employee.id=employee_images.emp_id;

This way you get all the records in empolyees and information about images if they exist